# Dynamically create tabs in Tablayout from a list?

Tags: java, android

My app creates drawer submenus from sharedpreference values. These submenus are basically called "interests" or categories. I'm trying to move this same functionality to tablayout since that is much more convenient but can't seem to get it to work!

**Edit**: ***New code based on suggestions.***

**TabsFragment**:

```
public class HomeTabsFragment extends Fragment implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {

    private View view;
    private SectionsPagerAdapterHome homePageAdapter;
    public ViewPager viewPager;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        this.view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_articles_tabs, container, false);

        TabLayout tabLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.home_list_tabs);
        viewPager = view.findViewById(R.id.home_list_tabs_container);

        homePageAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapterHome(getFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(homePageAdapter);
        viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(tabLayout.getTabCount());
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(this);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        if(SharedPrefernces.getUserInterests()!=null) {
            List<String> my_interests = SharedPrefernces.getUserInterests();
            Collections.sort(my_interests, String::compareToIgnoreCase);
            my_interests.add(0, getString(R.string.all_stories));
            for (String interest : my_interests) {
                homePageAdapter.addTabPage(new FeedsFragment(), interest);
            }

        }

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        // Do something that differs the Activity's menu here
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        return false;
    }


    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {

        Fragment fragment = homePageAdapter.getFragment(position);
        if (fragment != null) {
            fragment.onResume();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

    }
}
```

**Adapter**:

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapterHome extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    private ArrayList fragmentTags = new ArrayList();
    private ArrayList<String> titles = new ArrayList();

    protected SectionsPagerAdapterHome(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm, FragmentPagerAdapter.BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT);
        fragmentManager = fm;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        Object object = super.instantiateItem(container, position);
        if (object instanceof Fragment) {
            Fragment fragment = (Fragment) object;
            String tag = fragment.getTag();
            fragmentTags.add(position, tag);
        }
        return object;
    }

    public Fragment getFragment(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        Object tag = fragmentTags.get(position);
        if (tag != null) {
            fragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(String.valueOf(tag));
        }
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return FeedsFragment.newInstance();
    }

    public void addTabPage(Fragment fragment,String title) {
        titles.add(title);
        fragmentTags.add(fragment);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragmentTags.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return titles.get(position);
    }
}
```

I'm not sure how I can achieve this so need help.

Comment: You have to add the item in the adapter.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using a `ViewPager` with an `Adapter` instead of using `tabLayout.addTab(...)` you have to add the item in the adapter.
Something like:

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapterHome extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
   

   private ArrayList fragmentTags = new ArrayList();
   private ArrayList<String> titles = new ArrayList();
   
   //.....
        
   public void addTabPage(Fragment fragment,String title) {
          titles.add(title);
          fragmentTags.add(fragment);
          notifyDataSetChanged();
   }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragmentTags.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return tables.get(position);
    }
        
}
```

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The application's PagerAdapter changed the adapter's contents without calling PagerAdapter#notifyDataSetChanged! Expected adapter item count: 21, found: 23

Comment: I've edited the code in my question with your solution but I get "llegalStateException" error, so please check my edit? Thank you!